# An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly

Tags: python, windows, msvcrt

I started getting this error every time I try to:

- install Python package with installer
- use PyWin extension (through COM application)
- start Notepad++ (with Python script plugin)

This started to happen couple of days ago.

Dialog shows, I dismiss and everything runs fine, except it pops again and again

I reinstalled Python 2.7.3 on Windows XP SP3 32bit, then reinstalled PyWin extensions, but nothing changed.

Looking for answer here, I found that obviously some library is missing manifest declaration, but I can't figure which one. Or what is loaded by default in all above mentioned 3 scenarios. Does anyone maybe has an idea?

---

I found it - it's PyGTK. I installed it couple of days ago, and I did suspect on it, but wasn't sure and didn't wanted to mislead.
I renamed `gtk-2.0` folder in site-packages and dialog stopped to show

Will contact the team and report back if I have something

---

**Update**

I tried to contact PyGTK team, couple of days ago, but the list seems very low frequency, I wonder who uses PyGTK on Windows. This is the link to reported problem in case anyone cares: http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2012-November/020462.html

And in case anyone is curious what did I do with this error dialogs, here is answer: I used PyGTK as I needed it by one project, which I now compiled to executable and got rid of GTK from my Python packages.

Comment: +1 Same environment as yours, and exact same problem. Temporarily removing PyGTK from the python path fixes the issue. You should post your solution as an answer.. Out of curiosity, how did you figure it out? I have dozens of packages installed system-wide, I would never have found this on my own :)

Comment: Glad it helped you :) I don't remember what I did, but I guess I was doing some monkey logic on recent packages at the time, like trial and error rename package folders ;) But really, I'm quite happy that I compiled the project that was using pygtk, and removed pygtk from my packages, as it was also slowing down Python execution for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what application or library is failing to load, you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to show any missing dependencies.

Comment: There are no missing dependencies. One library is missing manifest, but I can't find which one

Comment: likely msvcrt iirc python2.7 uses crt 9 that is more pain than 8, fortunately with crt10 ms dropped the manifest hell, but unfortunately you need to compile yourself python2 if you want crt10, you can cheat by putting the 3 dll and the manifest in the executable directory and remove the path in the manifest xml, sometimes it works