# "R6034 An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly" after pygtk being installed

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, pygtk

I'm using python 2.7.9 and encountered a problem when installing pygtk.

It displayed `"Runtime error!...R6034 An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly"` when installing numpy/scipy after pygtk being installed.

I tried to figure it out by searching it in stackoverflow and found two similar questions: [Runtime error R6034 in embedded Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14552348/4453460) and [An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13182444/4453460).

So following the first one, I deleted the path corresponding to msvcr90.dll, however, it still cannot work. Then I chose to simply delete msvcr90.dll; at this time, this error wasn't presented when installing numpy/scipy, however, these two modules cannot work when simply typing "importing numpy/scipy".

I also renamed gtk-2.0 following the second one. Then numpy and scipy can be successfully installed. But it displayed `"Error processing line 3 of C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygtk.pth"` when installing matplotlib using pip.

I'm really confused about it. Can anybody provide some methods to fix it?

Comment: How did you install python and pygtk?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. using python-2.7.9.msi and pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.2.win32-py2.7.msi to install python and pygtk respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I've installed Python and PyGTK on 5+ machines, at least two of them brand new, clean builds of Win 7.

I've got the `An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly` error whenever I install a Python package as a windows installer (rather than using `pip`) on all these machines. It's annoying, but has never made a jot of difference, both Python and Gtk function correctly.

You've deleted `msvcr90.dll`, and that is why you get your `Error processing line 3...` If you look at this file, you'll see that line 3 is `import runtime`, and if you look further into the 'runtime' package, you'll see that this then tries to find the missing dll.

I think your best bet is to try to restore the missing file. If it's still in your recycle bin - great!
If not, the best thing to do is [reinstall the Visual C++ runtime library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I didn't get my "Error processing line 3..." after deleting msvcr90.dll. That happened after renaming the file gtk-2.0, at which msvcr90.dll is still in its original path. But still thanks again. Couple of days ago, I reinstalled my OS and now use windows 7. After that, all of them, including pygtk, numpy, scipy and matplotlib can be successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

I made this video to show my way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6jhR1VBfeU. I use Anaconda to embedded Python in my C++ application. I simply changed "msvcr90.dll" to "msvcr90.dll_hihi" in 3 folders: 
C:\Users\your user\Anaconda2\Library\bin, C:\Users\your user\Anaconda2 and C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client (for x64)